# This plugin file is using both CommonJS and ES6 module systems together which we don't support

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I develop a survey software, however, there is a problem with my gatsby-browser.js

Gatsby 2.8.2

```
PS C:\Users\Jovan Bienvenu\Desktop\polling-app> gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.074 s
error This plugin file is using both CommonJS and ES6 module systems together which we don't support.
You'll need to edit the file to use just one or the other.

plugin: C:/Users/Jovan Bienvenu/Desktop/polling-app/gatsby-browser.js

This didn't cause a problem in Gatsby v1 so you might want to review the migration doc for this:
https://gatsby.dev/no-mixed-modules
```

Comment: How are you importing the module in your code?

Comment: I did an npm install

Answer (score 2):

The polling-app demo code for integrating firebase auth with gatsby that you are using is written with V1 of Gatsby ... in V2 you can't mix es6 style imports and exports with early versions. -- that demo code uses exports.replaceRouterComponent while using import statements.

Fix it with the below:

```
const replaceRouterComponent = ({ history }) => {
  const ConnectedRouterWrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <FirebaseProvider firebase={firebase}>
      <Router history={history}>{children}</Router>
    </FirebaseProvider>
  );

  return ConnectedRouterWrapper;
};

export default replaceRouterComponent
```

However - that code is also missing the V2 switch away from React Router to @reach/router .

Basically its a old code and you should probably consider a different plugin or approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I was using

```
exports.something
```

to export the function, instead I needed to use

```
exports { something };
```